# Help needed to establish a conformal mapping

Tags: complex-analysis

Could anyone advise me on how to find a conformal map from $H=\{z \in \mathbb{C}: Re(z)>0\}$ to $A= \{z \in \mathbb{C}:|z|>1, |z-2|<3\} \ ?$ I tried to compose the map in terms of intermediate mappings to no avail.  I think the crucial step is to map $A$ to some half-strip. Hints will suffice, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here’s half the answer, because I’m guessing that you already know how to map the strip between two parallel lines onto the right-hand half-plane.

Your domain seems to be the region between two circles, centered at $0$ and $2$, respectively, tangent to each other at $-1$. The big circle passes also through $5$ on the real axis. Since a fractional-linear transformation turns circles into circles (or lines), if you send the point of tangency to infinity, the two circles will become parallel lines. So my first-step transformation is
$$
f(z)=\frac{z-1}{z+1}\,.
$$
You check that the inner circle goes to the imaginary axis, and the outer circle goes to the vertical line $x=2/3$. And the interior point $2$ goes to $1/3$, so your image-set is the strip between these two vertical lines. You take care of the rest.